# Relation between prime roots and residues mod 7

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

in the prime root chapter from my book it was mentioned that the powers of the primitive root mod 7 equals the residues if you are calculating $\frac{1}{7}$.

It is easy to see that $3$ is a primitive root mod $7$ with
$$ 3^1 \equiv 3, 3^2 \equiv 2, 3^3 \equiv 6, 3^4\equiv 4, 3^5 \equiv 5, 3^6\equiv 1$$

So you get the sequence $3,2,6,4,5,1$.

Now let's calculate $1/7$ by hand. You get $10=1\cdot7+3, 30=4\cdot7+2, 20=2\cdot7+6 , \ldots.$

So the residues you get while calculating $1/7=\overline{142857}$ are identical to the powers of the primitive root $3$. If you calculate $2/7, 3/7, \ldots$, it just shift the sequence, but the pattern stays the same.

But this is not true for the other primitive root mod $7$ (namly $5$) and it is not true for any other primes but 7 i tested, like $5, 11,$ or $13$.

Now I really wonder, is this just a coincidence? And if not, what makes the number $7$ so special? Are there other numbers with a similar phenomenon?

Comment: @AlkaKadri Look at the residues in $10 = 1\cdot7 + \color{red}{3}, 30 = 4\cdot7 + \color{red}{2}$, etc.: these form the sequence $3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1$.

Comment: Calculate $\frac{1}{7}$ in base $5$. Generally, if $b$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, calculate $\frac{1}{p}$ in base $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work for the other primitive root $5$, provided you work in base $12$ instead of $10$. The sequence of powers is
$$5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 1$$.
Now calculate $1/7$ in base $12$:
$$12 = 1\cdot7 + 5,\quad 5\cdot12 = 60 = 8\cdot 7 + 4,\quad 4\cdot12 = 48 = 6\cdot 7 + 6, \ldots$$
The sequence $5, 4, 6, \ldots$ turns up again. In general, if $r$ is a primitive root mod $p$, try calculating $1/p$ in base $p + r$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the recursion $\bmod 7$ is simply $\,  d_1 \equiv 10,\ d_{k+1}\equiv 10\:\!d_k,\, $ so $\,d_k\equiv 10^k\equiv 3^k$.

The same will occur in any radix congruent to the base of the power sequence.